# Travel Stack Exchange - Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

For our sincere thanks to you for *being awesome* and making this site a success, if your name is on the first two pages of:

https://travel.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

... I'll be contacting you soon to send you a little care package. Inside a little blue box of awesomeness you'll find:

#### Stickers

[image: Stickers]

#### T-Shirts

[image: Shirts]

#### TOWELS!

[image: Towels]

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much - we've got some in reserve we can send to you for events, and since the site is now fully graduated you'll be seeing me a few times a year here on meta to hold a fun and impromptu contest.

I'll be reaching out to you at some point this week, so be sure to fill out the form as soon as it's convenient to do so. Shipping generally takes six to eig.. *oh why do I even bother giving reasonable and correct approximations when nobody is going to believe me anyway?*

Thanks to all of you for making this site great!

Comment: Wow, thanks! We've all been waiting for them towels ever since the site has graduated! Cheers, SE guys and gals!

Comment: btw the towel is microfiber, 15"x22"

Comment: Oh really? I didn't even know this was a thing. Awesome!

Comment: Right in the solar plexus! (=

Comment: OH MAN A TOWEL.

Comment: How amazing frood!

Comment: Heh if I qualify, they'll go right next to the Arqade and SF&F ones.  Towel looks a winner.

Comment: [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/38765), for those unfamiliar with the meme.

Comment: Fridge Magnets would have been nice. :)

Comment: I finally have a reason to return to the US!!!  (As if visiting my newborn niece isn't reason enough)

Comment: Arrived today. Thanks! Seems like this time the 6-8 weeks is actually right :-P

Comment: I'm sorry for this comment, but I saw such questions 2 or even 3 times from the site start, and all the times I've provided my address in Russia. Can you please say, are there any chances to track the presents on their way? Or some status for this sending?

Comment: Apparently mine just arrived in New Zealand, so I'll see them in two weeks' time :) Thanks Tim!

Comment: I got mine today. I'll *proudly* wear it in my next big trip (Malaysia, July). Thank you very much guys, specially @ThorstenS who was kind to offer his present to me.

Comment: Two months later, still got no info about the tracking. @Tim Post, can you please provide some news for it?

Comment: @VMAtm Our warehouse sent out the stuff to everyone that filled out the form several weeks ago, so something is definitely wrong if you didn't receive your stuff. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Tim Post, thank you for the reply. Hope everything is ok, and this is simply post problems..

Comment: @VMAtm I'm sure it's something silly. The worst case scenario is me sending it out to you again, so don't worry :)

Comment: @TimPost Hi there, there is still no information? May be you have a old tracking code I could check here for?

Comment: So, when are we restarting this program? :)

Comment: Looks quite different in real, specially colour.

Answer (score 8):

God I wish had enough rep to get in the first two pages. for those who are eligible, I must say the T Shirt is looking really great!

Comment: There will be plenty of opportunities to get one. I'm transitioning our 'swag program' (if you can call it that) to make sure everyone gets a chance to earn a shirt _somehow_. There are people that love and give lots of time to this site that probably won't ever be in the top 2 or even 5 pages. The mini contests are great for this, similar to the ones I held during Winter Bash on MSO. Everyone has a fantastic time with a bit of fun, and 10 more awesome people get swag.

Comment: Thanks @TimPost - more adventures ahead it seems!

Comment: @AyeshK: You can have my package. Tim, I send you a confirmation per mail.

Comment: @ThorstenS. aw thanks a lot! I just got your email.

Comment: @ThorstenS - thanks a lot once again! I got the t shirt, towel and stickers today. Means a lot to me.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I got it! Oh, man, thank you so much for the delivery! I'm going to provide the photo soon, and still - thank you so much!
Best SE site ever!